# alter query to return a list of followers to include a followedBack field

Tags: mysql, sql, case, inner-join

I have a table called favourites with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `favourites` (
`ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `followerID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `followedID` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=615 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I have a web service to retrieve a list of users who are following me.

```
SELECT ID, followerID, FName, SName , pic
FROM Favourites 
INNER JOIN users
ON users.UserID = Favourites.followerID 
WHERE followedID = ?
ORDER BY ID Desc
LIMIT  ?, 10
```

where the param passed into the where condition is the user in question retrieving their list of followers.

I need to add an additional field to this response to indicate whether I am also following them.

My initial attempt to add this in was as follows but I am getting a syntax error.

```
SELECT ID, followerID, FName, SName, pic, count(SELECT followerid from favourites where followedid = 36) as amFollowing 
FROM Favourites 
INNER JOIN users
ON users.UserID = Favourites.followerID 
WHERE followedID = 36
ORDER BY ID Desc
LIMIT  0, 10
```

I'm finding it difficult to get my head around, if anyone has any advice on how to approach this? Should I add an isFollowedBack column and update that on the fly or is there an easy way to achieve what I want without changing the table structure? Maybe I should be using CASE to compute it on the fly?

Update based on Linoff's answer:

```
    SELECT ID, followerID, FName, SName, pic, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM favourites f2 WHERE f2.followedid = f.followerId and f2.followerid = 36 ) as amFollowing 
FROM Favourites f 
INNER JOIN users u ON u.UserID = f.followerID 
WHERE followedID = 36 
ORDER BY ID 
Desc limit 0, 10
```

(36 being the userID of the person making the request)

Running an explain returns:

```
id             :      1
select_type    :      PRIMARY
table          :      f
type           :      index
possible_keys  :      NULL
key            :      PRIMARY
key_len        :      4
ref            :      NULL
rows           :      10
Extra          :      Using where


id             :      1
select_type    :      PRIMARY
table          :      u
type           :      eq_ref
possible_keys  :      PRIMARY
key            :      PRIMARY
key_len        :      4
ref            :      DBName.f.followerID
rows           :      1
Extra          :      NULL

id             :      2
select_type    :      DEPENDENT SUBQUERY
table          :      f2
type           :      ALL
possible_keys  :      NULL
key            :      NULL
rows           :      716
Extra          :      Using where
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected output. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can move the `count()` into the subquery:

```
SELECT ID, followerID, FName, SName, pic,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM favourites f2
        WHERE f2.followedid = f.followedId
       ) as amFollowing 
FROM Favourites f INNER JOIN
     users u
     ON u.UserID = f.followerID 
WHERE followedID = 36
ORDER BY ID Desc
LIMIT 0, 10;
```

You should also get into the habit of using table aliases and qualified column names in your queries.

Comment: sorry just getting back to this now, your query returned, the number of followers which each of the requesting user's followers has, as opposed to whether or not the user calling the web service is following back their follower. Hope that's clear, it's hard to explain. I got the query working based on your suggestion though so thanks for that, now i have the issue that when I run explain I see that the where query has a type of 'ALL' which is not good! I'll update my question now